# About norm on polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Is it possible to construct a norm on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that satisfies the following condition: There exists a $C>0$ such that for any two polynomials $p,q$:

$||p(x,y) q(x,y)||<=C||p(x,y)||\cdot||q(x,y)||$

At first I thought this would follow from Cauchy-Swartz, but I'm talking about polynomial multiplication on the left side, so no inner product. If this is not possible, would it be possible to choose a norm such that $C$ that only depends on $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sup/max-norm trivially fulfills this:
$$
\|p\| := \max_{|x|\le1} |p(x)|.
$$
This is a norm on these polynomials. Because for polynomials  $\|p\|=0$ implies $p=0$.
Then clearly for $x\in \mathbb C^2$ with $|x|\le 1$
$$
|p(x)q(x)|\le |p(x)| \cdot |q(x)| \le \|p\|\cdot \|q\|.
$$